# Get non filtered index for ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs

Imagine a simple ng-repeat with custom filter function, that will filter all the values that has an index different from 2 and 4 for example. Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in arr | filter:myFilter() track by $index">{{$index}}</div>
```

The output would be `<div>0</div><div>1</div>`. But how can I display the real array indexes, like `<div>2</div><div>4</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `$index` always has value of filtered element. The only solution is to loop through unfiltered array and add your custom `index` property:

```
myService.getData().then(function (results) {
    angular.forEach(results, function (result, i) {
        result.index = i;
    });

    $scope.array = results;
});
```